# Private Delegated method

Tags: kotlin, delegation

I am using class delegation in Kotlin and wondering if it is possible to make the delegated method private in Kotlin

```
interface A{
   fun test(name: String) 
 } 
class A1:A{
  fun test(name: String): String = name
}
interface C{
  fun myTest(name: String)
}
class C1(a:A){
  fun myTest(name: String) = a.test(name)
}  
class B(a:A): C by C1(a) {
 // I can call "mytest" here 
 fun anotherMethod() = myTest("hi") 
 //But I want to make "myTest" private
}
val b = B(A1()) 
//This should not be possible
//b.myTest()
```

Comment: Can you fix your code above so we can understand more clearly what you're attempting?  This line doesn't make semantic sense and won't compile: `class B(a:A): c by C(a) {` There is no interface C.

Comment: Sorry ! I have fixed the code.

Comment: Kotlin only supports delegation for interfaces, which exclusively have public members. For it to work for protected members, there would have to be some kind of "protected interface", which I doubt they will ever support because of the narrow usefulness and lack of support on the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Interface is used to expose functions for public API, if B is A, then it must have a public member test.

You shouldn't implement A if you don't want test() to be available as public member:

```kotlin
class B(val a: A) {
    fun anotherMethod() = a.test("hi")
}
```

Comment: This is fine but I wanted some way to make it private. In Ruby, We have ways to make delegated method private. in ROR 6 you can just do
`delegate :first_name, :last_name, to: :@user, private: true` and first_name and last_name  will be private

Comment: @Arithmeticbird there is no interface involved in there [if I pointed to correct post](https://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-delegate), The kotlin has strict type system, ruby doesn't seem to have (as there were no type annotation involved). What do you need to make private btw? The visibility is defined as public in interface and inheritors must follow it. Why do you want to implement `interface A`?

Comment: well yes, I made changes in the example to make intention explicit. In explicit delegation (without kotlin language support) I can easily make the method private.  I can't see why we can not do this with language support.
Explicit delegation
`class B(val a: A) {
    fun anotherMethod() = a.test("hi")
    private fun test(name:String) = a.test(name)
}`

Comment: `I can't see why we can not do this with language support.`, Because you implement the interface A, you have to "define" public method test(). You can however override it so that it doesn't do anything but you have to implement it as you are saying B is subtype of A.